# How can i recover my corrupted 7Zip file

Tags: backup, compression, 7-zip, file-recovery, recovery

While using Linux, I compressed my backup using 7zip and transferred it to a USB disk. Due to an error in the system, the data transfer process froze while the data transfer was about to end. After waiting for about half an hour, I thought it was over and removed my USB disk from my computer. When I try to open my backup after switching to Windows, I get the error "Can not open file 'backup.7z' as archive". https://7-zip.org/recover.html I found this resource but couldn't understand anything. What can I do about this, the data in the backup is very important to me.

Comment: The whole idea of a backup is that it is a duplicate of data held elsewhere; hopefully in more than one other location. If it is the only copy, it isn't a backup.

Comment: Yeah it was the only copy so how can i recover my data

Answer (score 0):

Your resource contains education for IT-oriented people interested in recovery.
Your either bite the bullet and learn the stuff and program software for recovery or you have to pay someone to do that for you.

Right now (16.7.2021) 7-Zip does not possess built-in recovery functions as opposed to RAR (https://www.rarlab.com/).

Luckily you most probably won't need the abilities of a professional recovery lab as your problems seems to related only to software.
You should get a lower price quoted as you only need an interested programmer.